# git - update fork's master & rebase my branch onto it?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a github project, then cloned it locally.

I then made some changes in a new branch on `my_github/the_project` repo.

I then added and committed the changes and pushed to my github repo and submitted a pull request.

The owner has received my request and would like me to "rebase onto master" to get the latest changes.  How do I do this?

Initially I thought I could just `git fetch` and `rebase master` from within my current branch (as most posts I found advise...), but `git fetch` didn't do anything.  Now I've realized that it is presumably because I'm still fetching from `my_ github/repo` clone (it's my name in the remotes after all) which hasn't yet got the new changes in master from the github source owner.

I think what I probably need to do is "refresh" *my* fork so that my fork's master is up-to-date and *then* I can fetch that master and *then* rebase on to that master?

If this is the case how can I do that refresh of my forks master?  If not how else?

Should I add a remote for the original upstream repository and use that to rebase with (locally)?  Is this the preferred method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's not fetching anything because of the reason you surmised. And yes, you should add a remote for upstream locally; it will do a fast-forward merge on master.

```
git checkout master # Make sure you are in master
git remote add author original_repo_that_you_forked_from
    # Note: This is in the format git@github.com:authors_name/repo_name.git
    #       Only needs definition once, future fetches then use it. 
git fetch author
git status # make sure you are in the master branch for the following merge
git merge author/master  # i.e. 'into' your master branch
git checkout your-branch
git rebase master        # Now get those changes into your branch.
git push origin your_branch # You can also use `-f` if necessary and `--all`
```

(sorry, I might not have the syntax exactly right)

Comment: You might want to specify the remote in the push, like `git push origin --all`, but otherwise that is exactly what I'd suggest.

Comment: From this github [rebase and merge blog](https://github.com/blog/2243-rebase-and-merge-pull-requests), can we say that even if the contributor has not rebased the change, it should be very convienient for the _author_ to rebase and merge? If this is the case, I don't understand why a PR is put on hold because it's not rebased.

Comment: Because if there are conflicts, the maintainer won't necessarily know how to fix them. The author is best placed to fix them.