# git pull request and rebase

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

I have a little problem with my git.

I fork one project on github, i change and commit some file.

Now i want to do "Pull  request" with option rebase.

I do a Pull Request but how can i rebase the pull request ?
Did the original author of the repo need to accept my pull request and after i can or he can rebase, or i need to rebase after the pull request ?

Comment: `git pull` is not the same thing as a pull request. `git pull` is the command you use to pull changes from a remote repo into your repo. A pull request is when you ask someone with a remote copy of the repo to do a `git pull` from your repository to theirs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git pull` command does *not* create a GitHub Pull Request!

A GitHub Pull Request is, as the name suggests, a request, for *someone else* to perform a pull into their repository.

The standard way to create a pull request is to `git push` your commits up to your fork, and then create a pull request in the GitHub web interface for the repository you want your commit to be pulled into.

However, GitHub also offers a git extension called `hub` which adds extra subcommands to `git` to help to do things like this.

To rebase before issuing your pull request, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884206/git-how-to-update-my-forks-master-so-i-can-rebase-my-branch-onto-it/19884276#19884276) for an example way to do it - which may have to be tweaked for your particular circumstances.

Comment: Well after i pull Request what i need to do for rebase the branch master ? Did the original author of the repo need to accept my pull request and after i can or he can rebase, or i need to rebase after the pull request ?

Comment: @Martialp `Git checkout mybranch` then  `git rebase master` `git push origin +mybranch`  here origin is your github location which you can confirm using `git remote -v`

Comment: yeah, your answer on the on the other topic is really clear ! :) thx a lot.